# relation between kubernetes and cron

Tags: linux, kubernetes, cron

I am operating kubernetes.
There are many terminating pods.
And So many crond daemons are in place in VM.
both /var/log/messages and /var/log/crond are empty.

I don't know why crond daemon is occurred so many?

500 Crond daemons are excecuting.

## ps -ef | grep crond | wc -l

648

and load average is 16

I want to know relations between crond and pod terminating on kubernetes.

How Could I dertermine ?
I checked /etc/rsyslog.conf - it's normal.

Comment: Are you maybe seeing CronJob objects? Those use "cron" in the name but are not related to `crond` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

By default `cron` emails the program output to the user who owns a particular `crontab`, therefore you can check whether any of the emails have been delivered within default path `/var/spool/mail`.

When you have a long-running or continuous script that could never be finished in `cron`, it can produce a multiple `cron` processes appearing in the process list, therefore it might be useful to get a list with a tree view on `crontab specific parent/child processes:

`pstree -ap| grep crond`

I assume that you have a large CPU utilization on your VM, which can potentially degrade the overall performance and affect Kubernetes engine. Although, Kubernetes provides a comprehensive mechanism for managing [Compute resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/), it distributes resources allocated on a specific Node within Pods which are consuming CPU and RAM on that Node.

To check general resource utilization on a particular Node, you can use this command:

`kubectl describe node <node-name>`

To check a Pod terminating reason, you can use similar command as in the above example:

`kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`

However, when you require to dig deeper into the troubleshooting action on your Kubernetes cluster, I would recommend to look at the official [Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/troubleshooting/).